# Is there a way to move the x when hovering on mxgraph vertext?

Tags: mxgraph

[image]

As you can see there is a x when I'm hovring on mxgraph vertex. I need to remove it. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the grapheditor example.

If you want to remove them all, you have to exclude the Constraints from the Shape.js
[GraphEditor - Shape.js](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/master/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/js/Shapes.js#L3770)

If you want to exclude them only from the cylinder, you need to check from which class your shape is derived from and then exclude only those constraints.

Comment: I'm trying to add anchors and have some issue. if anyone can look at my issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57660955/add-anchors-to-mxgraph